# Deploying SQL Anywhere 10 Runtime Engine

Tags: sqlanywhere

I'm trying to deploy the Sybase SQL Anywhere 10 Runtime Engine, but I'm having some problems. When I run my application, I get an error:

> **SQLSTATE = IM003**
>
> Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 193 (`cinema_ConfigurationDriver`).

According to my research, this is indicative of a missing DLL. I am looking at documentation on what and how to deploy. That documentation is from [the Sybase SyBooks Online site](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc37774_1100/html/apptech/BGBCBACD.htm)

I have copied the indicated file into my application directory. I have also created the registry entries as indicated with two changes. Instead of calling the driver `SQL Anywhere 10.0` I have called it `cinema_ConfigurationDriver`.

And I did not create the DSN entry; I am using a DSN-less connection in my PowerBuilder 11.5 code.

Comment: Okay, so I uninstalled the full version of SQL Anywhere 10. I then installed just the runtime engine using the Sybase-provided installer. I checked that documentation and copied the listed files into my application directory. I also added the "START" command to my connection string. It worked. However...

Comment: However, all is not well. I then uninstalled the SQLA10 runtime engine. I still had all of the documented files in my application directory. My "START" command explicitly gives the path to rteng10.exe. Upon trying to run my application now, I get:

 ---------------------------
 Error
 ---------------------------
 SQLSTATE = 08001
 
 [Sybase][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Unable to start specified database: failure code 1
 ---------------------------
 OK    
 ---------------------------

Answer (score 1):

I know zilch about PowerBuilder, and I have no idea what "cinema" refers to, but I do know that there are no error messages in SQL Anywhere that contain "cinema". However, "Unable to start specified database" is definitely a SQL Anywhere error message. Can you post the full contents of your connection string? (You can either update your question or add a comment to this answer.)

**Edit** after OP comment:

You don't need to specify the `-ga` switch, since the client library will add it for you (unless you use the AUTOSTOP=NO connection parameter), and you shouldn't add the `-n` switch to the START line, since that's what the ENG parameter is for. Neither of these will cause your problem however. The obvious thing to check is that you've specified the correct path to the .db file and that you have permission to modify the file. If that's OK, you could add the `LOG=<filename>` parameter to the connection string, and then check the contents of that file for more detailed information.

Comment: ---------------------------
Config
---------------------------
ConnectString='Driver=cinema_ConfigurationDriver;ENG=cinema_Configuration;DBF=C:\Documents and Settings\Jason\My Documents\PharMax\Code\CINEMA 2.0\configuration.db;UID=CINEMA;PWD=******;START=C:\Documents and Settings\Jason\My Documents\PharMax\Code\CINEMA 2.0\rteng10.exe -ga -qw -qi -n cinema_Configuration -sb 0'
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

Comment: "CINEMA" is my application. I'm creating the SQL Anywhere driver under a different name. You *should* be able to replace "cinema_ConfigurationDriver" with "SQL Anywhere 10.0"... that's the goal, at least.

Comment: The log file contains:

10:21:50 Attempting to connect to a running server...
10:21:50 Attempting SharedMemory connection (no sasrv.ini cached address)

10:21:50 Failed to connect over SharedMemory

10:21:50 No server found, attempting to run START line...
10:21:51 Failed to autostart server
10:21:51 Attempting SharedMemory connection (no sasrv.ini cached address)

10:21:51 Failed to connect over SharedMemory

10:21:51 Cannot connect to server

Comment: My guess is that it has to do with the spacey filenames. Try putting quotes around them. Beyond that, I think this is more of a question for Sybase tech support than a question suitable for Stack Overflow. Try the newsgroups at http://www.sybase.com/support/community-forums